# How to link a webpage to itself without first knowing its name?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

To link a page to itself (e.g. http://example.com/folder/ThisPage.html), we can simply create a href as such:

**ThisPage.html**:

```
<a href="ThisPage.html">Link</a>
```

This works, but has the disadvantage of needing to be *updated* when the file name changes. For example, if the file name changes to `ThatPage.html`, our href needs to change accordingly to `<a href="ThatPage.html">Link</a>`.

I'm looking for an alternative without that disadvantage. I've tried:

- `<a href="?">Link</a>`

  Doesn't work as `<a href="ThisPage.html">Link</a>` does, because it appends a "blank query part" (question mark) to the URL.
- `<a href="">Link</a>`

  Doesn't work as `<a href="ThisPage.html">Link</a>` does, on some browsers (e.g. Opera).

How do we link a page to itself, without having to update the relevant portion when the name of the page changes?

<sub>Note: JavaScript not allowed.</sub>

Comment: what do you expect a page that links to itself to do? Do you expect it to go to a specific section of the site or open a new page?

Comment: @scrappedcola. It loads a page that has the same URL as itself. (some may call this a "refresh")

Comment: Since this is a valid question... so I was wondering  why the downvote?

Comment: This question looks fine to me, my guess is that someone just went "oh its a HTML question, it must be easy" and reflexively downvoted without really reading it.

Comment: Just curious, on which browsers does `<a href="">` not work?

Comment: @Juhana, Opera latest version (v12.14 and I believe the earlier versions too). Instead of submitting a GET to the URL, it submits a *re-action* to the URL. Which means **that innocuous `<a href="">Link</a>` actually does a POST in Opera** if the current action of the page was POST.

Comment: Oh, phew. I've been using `""` and was worried that it would introduce problems with major browsers. (No disrespect to Opera of course.)

Comment: lol me too, realised it only when it broke a page when testing with Opera. Works fine on Chrome, IE, FF, Safari though.

Comment: @Pacerier - Works with Opera on my end though. "Opera/9.80  Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14"

Comment: @Bart, are you sure? I'm having the same version: *Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14*. Did you test with the current page being POSTed?

Comment: @Pacerier - You're right about the page being POSTed. However. When the page in question is cached it's not. Since retrieving from cache has no METHOD.

Comment: @Bart, And so `<a href="">Link</a>` fails to meet the requirement, which is doing what `<a href="ThisPage.html">Link</a>` does, at least in major browsers.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `<a href="?">Link</a>`. Nobody cares about the question mark appended to the URL. It does the requirement and that is what counts right?

Comment: `.` would drop the file name (`example.com/foo/bar.html` would become `example.com/foo/`).

Comment: Ah ok. Changed my answer to it's original form ;_)

Comment: @Bart, to us it's just a question mark. to the server this is a completely different page.

Comment: @Pacerier - That should not be the case. And if it is. The server config is faulty. The `?` denotes the start of a query string and not a location.

Comment: @Bart, unlike `#`, `?` is a part of the URL (per RFC). It's presence modifies the URL. The server sees it as two different URLs, although it may return the same resource if it *wants* to.

Comment: If so. Why would it be a problem? I'm curious to know.

Comment: @Bart, because even though *your* server may return the same resource, the server I'm on isn't configured to do so. It will break my page in many ways, including spoil caching etc.

Comment: @Pacerier True. Thank you for clarifying. I learned a lot in the meanwhile, so I don't really agree with my own comments stated above anymore :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple, just leave the `href=""` blank. So that's how:

```
<a href="">Click me to refresh page</a>
```

But this is not necessarily a good idea, because the cache may not be cleared, and whatever you need it for, if the page has changed in the meantime the change may not appear despite the reload. Probably a better idea is the javascript code `location.reload();` to take. But there are enough explanations on other sites, which is why I won't explain it here. You can of course also for example take a question mark (?), but this is unnecessary, actually not intended for it and can cause problems depending on the program.

---

### Here is a short list of common hyperlinks:

Points to the root page

```
<a href="/">Link</a>
```

Points to a file relative to the root page

```
<a href="/file.ext">Link</a>
```

Points to a file relative to the current file

```
<a href="file.ext">Link</a>
```

Points to a file in the previous folder

```
<a href="../file.ext">Link</a>
```

Points to a file in the second previous folder

```
<a href="../../file.ext">Link</a>
```

Points to a file in a folder below

```
<a href="folder/file.ext">Link</a>
```

Points to the current file

```
<a href="">Link</a>
```

Points to a page with a different host but the same protocol

```
<a href="//domain.tld/file.ext">Link</a>
```

I hope that my answer will help some people, because I found it via a search engine and saw that there is no correct answer. And it's my first answer here

**Edit (after two and a half years):**

I just searched for the official specifications and this is what I found:

*Same-document References*

“A URI reference that does not contain a URI is a reference to the
current document.  In other words, an empty URI reference within a
document is interpreted as a reference to the start of that document, […]”

That means, as I sad, this kind of hyperlink doesn’t necessarily reload the page. As a pure HTML solution, this is not possible.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2396#section-4.2

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to go nowhere, you can use

```
<a href="javascript:;">link</a>
```

But if you want it to reload the page, you'll have to go with JavaScript.

If you want to reload the page you could use the Meta refresh tag

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

Comment: Meta refresh also requires us to state the URL explicitly... Yes, relying on JavaScript will definitely do the trick (since we can read `window.location`), but I'm wondering if there exists a non-JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **reload** the page, you really should take a look into javascript. It is the best way to do it.

Comment: Yes, relying on JavaScript will definitely do the trick (since we can read window.location), but I'm wondering if there exists a non-JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
<a href = "/">This Very Site</a>
```

Source: I saw this in the source code of [Matthew Alger's website](http://www.matthewja.com). Check it out for yourself!

Comment: This doesn't work. Try it. It links to the top page `http://example.com/` and not to the current page (unless the current page *is also* the top page)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try `<a href="./"></a>`?

I looked some things up, and as it turns out, `./` refers to current directory.

Answer (score -1):

You can just make a link to the same page.

Comment: Yes, but that, as stated in the question, has the disadvantage of having to be updated when the page name changes.

Answer (score -3):

Here ya go. Hope this is what you are looking for

```
    <a href="#">Link</a>
```

Comment: This will only jump to the top of the page. It doesn't trigger a page refresh.

Comment: read [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479551/Reloading-The-Page.htm) **bold** have you tried using the full url? <a href=http://www.fullurl.com/yourpage.html>refresh</a>

Comment: Did you read the question? The OP specifically doesn't want to hard-code the full url in.